# How to run an operation for exactly x seconds in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've following code,

```js
console.time("a");
var i = 0;
var intervalID = setInterval(function () {
    i++;
    if( i == 100){
        window.clearInterval(intervalID);
        console.timeEnd("a");
    }
}, 1);
```

It outputs following,

> a: 389.15380859375ms

Generally, the code runs for more than  `100 ms`. But if you see the code, the code should have been completed in 100ms, atleast I was expecting it to run in 100 ms. I'm okay with `100 +/- 10 ms`, but the output is 3 times, which is unacceptable for my use-case. Basically, I want to run a operation for 100 ms, above code is just a sample. So, what am I missing? How do I run the code precisely for 100 ms?

Comment: What do you mean? I can't give 1ms as argument to `setInterval` method? If that is the case, how do I run the code for 100 ms? I'm open for suggestions

Comment: Do you want to run _any_ code and then interrupt it if it’s been running for longer than a certain amount of time (eg to avoid infinite loops), or do you want to repeat  instructions until a certain amount of time has passed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `setInterval` method has a minimum working value of 4ms.  This is described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified).

If I produce the same code but with 10 x 10ms intervals, you get close to 100ms:

```js
console.time("a");
var i = 0;
var intervalID = setInterval(function () {
    i++;
    if( i == 10){
        window.clearInterval(intervalID);
        console.timeEnd("a");
    }
}, 10);
```

It's worth noting that `setInterval` may not be precise.  Look:

> In addition to "clamping", the timeout can also fire later when the
>   page (or the OS/browser itself) is busy with other tasks

You cannot *guarantee* that you will get exactly 100ms with `setInterval`.

Comment: Awesome. This works for me. Out of curiosity, Is there a way to be very precise?

Comment: You can use `Date` to get precise time measurements (at least down to the millisecond), which you could use to time your operations.  However, it may be worth considering whether you need such precision, and if you do, whether JS is the right place to host such precise operations

Comment: What ControlAltDel wrote is actually more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Just check the time in your interval

```
console.time("a");
var i = 0;
var endtime;
var intervalID = setInterval(function () {
   if (!endtime) {
     endtime = Date.now() + 100;
   }
   if (Date.now() > endtime) {
     clearInterval(intervalID);
     console.timeEnd("a");
     return;
   }
   i++;
   //console.log(i);
   //doSomethingWithI(i);
}, 1);
```

Comment: Doesn't help. It still outputs ~389ms

Comment: huh... I see, you have edited the answer and now it gives right answer. Thank you for this solution.